# Can javascript pick up inbound links

Tags: javascript, jquery, tcp

Can a jquery or javascript pick up inbound links on a page?
For example, I need to determine whether a page was a) reloaded b) entered from a foreign link or c) clicked on by a link within my domain name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use document referrer for this.

```
document.referrer
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer

Comment: The whole history of the previous few links is there in cases that are more complicated. But it can be modified to some degree by the javascript on the previous pages, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`document.referrer` will tell you the URL of the page that the user came from, or will be empty on Refresh.

But I wouldn't base any security-sensitive code on it - the equivalent  `Referer` (sic) HTTP header is easy to spoof, and I suspect `document.referrer` is too.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the referrer headers - found in document.referrer This will tell you details of where the link has come from.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
document.referrer
```

For more info, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. The CGI might be available to you depending on your platform, which you may be able to systematically make available to js.

However, you can also try this: `console.log(document.referrer);`

I don't think there is a systematic way to check a 'reload'. But by comparing `document.referrer` with `location.hostname` or other properties of `location`, you can determine foreign/internal clicks/links. A reload would perhaps be determined by having the same internal referrer as the current page (and queryString values).